# Update stored records numbers depending on previous rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to create script that will set the column of one table in databse based on these conditions:

- Every Selling order (table selling_order) has record in Selling order person (table selling_order_person) where is email of person stored
- I have to order all records in selling_order by order_time ASC (so the oldest orders will be first) and on these orders I have to set the column of selling_order name rank (that is column repesents how many orders customer alredy did. Its based on email in selling_order_person). So the first order of customer will have 1, the second one will have 2 etc. And this have to be done for one customer.
- All this logic will be stored in liquibase (so it will run just once, the next records will be managed by Java on the row creation. But the old data have to be managed first via liquibase).

I´ve written this procedure. But it does not work, It just set number 1 to half of a table (it is possible cause its testing table so there could be cases where selling_order_person have no mail or no record).
Can anyone help me with that? Its my first SQL procedure so I dont know whats wrong.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateSellingOrderCustomerCount()
    RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
    t_curs CURSOR FOR SELECT so.*, sop.email
                      FROM selling_order so
                               INNER JOIN selling_order_person sop on so.person_id = sop.id
                      ORDER BY order_time;
BEGIN
    FOR tmp IN t_curs
        LOOP
            UPDATE selling_order
            SET rank =
                    (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(so.rank), 1)
                     FROM selling_order so
                              INNER JOIN selling_order_person sop on so.person_id = sop.id
                     WHERE sop.email = tmp.email)
            WHERE selling_order.id = tmp.id;
        END LOOP;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

SELECT * FROM updateSellingOrderCustomerCount();
```

**For simplicity Ive deleted all columns that we dont work with now.**

```
create table selling_order
(
    id bigserial not null
        constraint selling_order_pkey
            primary key,
    selling_order_person_id bigint not null,
    rank int,
    order_time timestamp
);

create index idx_selling_order_person_id
    on selling_order (person_id);


create table selling_order_person
(
    id bigserial not null
        constraint pk_selling_order_person
            primary key,
    email varchar(64)
);
```

Comment: Use triggers instead, to ensure data consistency. (Or only allow update/insert/delete via stored procedures.)

Comment: Well but I need to manage alredy existing records. So no trigger on insert wont work. I just need to set these data once and then It will be stored with proper value for new records. Thats whats Java will do on Selling order creation

Comment: Please post the schema (as a CREATE TABLE.. ) for both tables and some example data. I'm having a hard time understanding that big block of text at the top of the question that is describing the schema in words - i'd rather read it in SQL

Comment: Added. Ive skipped column we dont work with.

Comment: "*For simplicity Ive deleted all columns that we don't work with now*" - you also remove the `rank` and `order_time` columns which are essential for answering this question. I don't understand where exactly the column is located that defines the ordering to be used for the ranking

Comment: Where i that "customer" information you are referring to? Is a "customer" the same as "selling_order_person_id"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to a_horse_with_no_name. Ive just editted a little his code and it works like charm.

```
UPDATE selling_order so
    SET rank = tmp.rnk
    FROM (
             SELECT so.id, sop.email,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LOWER(sop.email) ORDER BY order_time) AS rnk
             FROM selling_order so
                      INNER JOIN selling_order_person sop ON so.selling_order_person_id = sop.id
         ) tmp
    WHERE tmp.id = so.id;
```

Comment: you don't have to JOIN with selling_order_person and partition by email when you can partition by  selling_order_person_id from selling_order table itself, just like it was done by a_horse_with_no_name. your additional join will only increase query execution time.

Comment: Well as I said, there is prolly missunderstanding. The records in selling_order_person are not unique for one email. There can be 50 rows in selling_order_person containing the same email (for every order where customer is not logged- so he enters his credentials every time on his own- is record. 1:1 with selling_order). So I cant join on selling_order_person id. Cause this causes that all orders have rank 1 (all IDS are unique)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this can be done with a single UPDATE statement

```
update selling_order so
  set rank = t.rnk
from (
  select id, 
         row_number() over (partition by selling_order_person_id order by order_time) as rnk
  from selling_order
) t
where t.id = so.id;
```

I assume that the customer you mention in "*how many orders customer already did*" refers to `selling_order_person_id` not to some hidden "customer" column.

Online example: https://rextester.com/ATD51610

---

But managing this `rank` column seems pretty useless, given the fact that you can easily calculate that information (as shown in the inner SELECT of the UPDATE statement)

Comment: First of all, the decision not to compute rank number on the fly was performance reason. The list of all selling_orders are often displayed. So compute that all over and over again would be useless. The second fact is that when I used your SQL the result was that rank column contains just 1 (even when there are multiple orders for person with same email)

Comment: Then you either did not run the statement as shown (because that clearly works with the information you have given: https://rextester.com/ATD51610) or you have left out some important details

Comment: Well there is some missunderstanding. Ive changed that a little and it works (Ill post it below). Cause I cant join over selling_order_person_id. I need to join on email. Its order without register so there can be for example 5 records with unique id but with same email.